# Special characters triggering jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with special characters triggering events in jQuery. I've got a div containing some text, when it's hovered I call a hover function, when it's "unhovered" I call another function. This works fine if I don't have any quotations: ' or " in the div contents, but causes the unhover event to trigger prematurely if those characters are in the div.

That is to say, the unhover event is being called when I'm still mousing over the div. I've tried using htmlentities, htmlspecialchars on the text in the div, but neither seem to help. Any ideas?

```
$('#elementID').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```

EDIT: I should add that the div's contents are being passed to it by php via a TWIG template variable.

Comment: I suggest you to give a reduced part of your html and to make a fiddle.

Comment: And also give us the exact contents of hoverIn and hoverOut if you're doing something complex in them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird. Content should not affect the hover event. It sounds like the div you are asigning the hover function doesn't cover the whole area and possibly another element inside is breaking your code, but without ckecking the actual code is hard to tell what's wrong.